# Angular Material Tabs + ui-router: body not loading

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

> **Update**: the use of `ui-sref` and `md-tabs` was fixed in Angular Material 0.10.0

First of all, we're aware there's several issues similar to this one. 
However, we've been trying for hours, and still no luck, so let's see if someone can shed a bit of light on this particular case.

We are trying to have two tabs, with two different views an two different controllers.

The tabs render fine, they work, and the URL changes on tab change, but the tab "body" is never loaded.

The ui-sref is defined in a span to avoid https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2344

**Module configuration**

```
  function testRouteConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('testTabs', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/test/tabs',
        templateUrl: 'modules/test/test.html',
        controller: 'TestController as vm'
      })
      .state('testTabs.testMain', {
        url: '/test/main',
        data: {
          'selectedTab': 0
        },
        views: {
          'testMain': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/test/main/mainTest.html',
            controller: 'MainTestController as vm'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('testTabs.testAbout', {
        url: '/test/about',
        data: {
          'selectedTab': 1
        },
        views: {
          'testAbout': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/test/about/aboutTest.html',
            controller: 'AboutTestController as vm'
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

**Tabs definition (test.html)**

```
<md-tabs md-selected="currentTab" md-stretch-tabs="always" class="main-toolbar">
  <md-tab>
    <md-tab-label><span ui-sref="testTabs.testMain">Profile</span></md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body ui-view="testMain" layout="vertical" layout-fill></md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <md-tab-label><span ui-sref="testTabs.testAbout">About</span></md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body ui-view="testAbout" layout="vertical" layout-fill></md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

**Main controller**

```
'use strict';

TestController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {
    $scope.currentTab = toState.data.selectedTab;
  });
}

module.exports = TestController;
```

**Example tab body**

```
<p>{{vm.title}}</p>
```

**Example tab controller**

```
'use strict';

AboutTestController.$inject = [];

function AboutTestController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.title = 'About Test page';
}

module.exports = AboutTestController;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think your routes are not as you want them to be. The url of a substate (state.substate) will be appended to the state's url. The url to your state `'testTabs.testMain'` would be `/test/tabs/test/main'`. If you want it to be absolute, you have to prepend a `^`: `^/test/main`. Or simply make it relative by removing the heading `/test`.

If that doesn't do the trick, try naming the views absolutely:

```
views: {
      'testMain@testTabs': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/test/main/mainTest.html',
        controller: 'MainTestController as vm'
      }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering! But I tried everything you said (and different combinations, and the result is the same: the navigation works (the URL changes), but nothing is loaded in the tab body. I'm really not sure that it's not a bug of the md-tabs, since there's a workaround without views in the linked issue: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2344

Comment: I've reproduced the same problem you have; nothing in the body loads and no errors are displayed. Naming the views didn't fix the problem.