# Make angularJS ui router work with angular material design TABS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, material-design

The TabControl is visible when the app starts but...

When I click on a tab NO content is visible

What do I wrong?

I use the latest angularJS material design 0.9.4.

```
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");
      $stateProvider

          .state("main",
          {
            abtract: true,
            url: '',
            views: {
              'content@': {
                templateUrl: '../app/views/administration/administration.html',
                controller: 'AdministrationController'
              }
            }
          })
          .state('main.settings', {
            url: '/settings',
            views: {
              'settings@main': {
                templateUrl: "../app/views/administration/settings.html",
                controller: 'GlobalConfigurationController'
              }
            }
          })
          .state('main.schoolyears', {
            url: '/schoolyears',
            views: {
              'schoolyears@main': {
                templateUrl: "../app/views/schoolyear/schoolyears.html",
                controller: 'SchoolyearsController'
              }
            }
          });
```

**HTML**

```
<div layout-fill layout="column">
  <div ng-include="'app/components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>
  <div id="content" layout="column" layout-padding>

    <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs="always" class="md-primary md-hue-2">

      <md-tab label="Schoolyears" ui-sref="main.schoolyears" md-active="$state.is('main.schoolyears')">
        <md-tab-body ui-view="schoolyears" layout="vertical" layout-fill></md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>

      <md-tab label="settings" ui-sref="main.settings" md-active="$state.is('main.settings')">
         <md-tab-body ui-view="settings" layout="vertical" layout-fill></md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>

    </md-tabs>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are sourcing the controllers with <script tag?

Comment: you want the controllers code? Or know wether I include the controller in the index.html?

Comment: I have no error in the browser console. Thus all files are included. All 3 controllers are empty with no code of mine. They also need no code to make the tab work. This is just a router/state and html problem.

Comment: ok. in that case, when you click on schoolyears tab, can you tell if schoolyears,html is getting called? via console?

Comment: there is NO output in the console.

Comment: It seems to be exactly the same as what happens to us: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356214/angular-material-tabs-ui-router-body-not-loading?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

> **Update**: the use of `ui-sref` and `md-tabs` was fixed in Angular Material 0.10.0

A workaround has been posted on github, on the [previous known md-tab issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2344):

There's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WVsbSHfplx82FXywYq2G?p=info) with the workaround (it seems to work without the views):

```
  $stateProvider
      .state('tabs', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/tabs',
        templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
        onEnter: function() { console.log("enter tabs.html"); } })

      .state('tabs.tab1', {
        url: '/tab1',
        onEnter: function() { console.log("enter tab1.html"); },
        controller: function($scope) {

        },
        templateUrl: 'tab1.html'
      })
      .state('tabs.tab2', {
        url: '/tab2',
        onEnter: function() { console.log("enter tab2"); },
        controller: function($scope) {

        },
        templateUrl: 'tab2.html'
      });
```

Comment: I know this is ond question, but I noticed that there is still one bug in Your Plunker. When You hit back arrow in browser tab content changes from `tab 2` to `tab 1` but `tab 2` is still selected (there is red line below `tab 2` when content says `tab 1`). Can this be fixed?

Comment: Please don't use that plunker anymore. It was made with an old version of Angular Material that needed the workaround to play nice with ui-router. It's not the case anymore.

Comment: You can see it working fine without the "span" hack here: http://plnkr.co/edit/psinbetM1CUBqIxuL1yq

Comment: Thank You for reply, but in Your latest Plunker when clicking `back` in browser `tab 1` isn't getting selected. I've tweaked Your code a bit and got this: http://plnkr.co/edit/4gKaghePnTMh4NgfQcxC?p=preview

Comment: Anyway thanks for answer, Your code helped me getting started

Comment: Cool! I'll take a look later, because I think we got it working fine in our app, I'll try to see if we do something different than in that plunker :)

Comment: I've just added `md-selected` in tabs template, this way I can set current tab :)